# Lags in R within specific subsets?

Tags: r, time-series, lag, zoo

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("yearmonth"=c("2005-01","2005-02","2005-03","2005-01","2005-02","2005-03"),"state"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),"county"=c(3,3,3,3,3,3),"unemp"=c(4.0,3.6,1.4,3.7,6.5,5.4))
```

I'm trying to create a lag for unemployment within each unique state-county combination. I want to end up with this:

```
df2 <- data.frame("yearmonth"=c("2005-01","2005-02","2005-03","2005-01","2005-02","2005-03"),"state"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),"county"=c(3,3,3,3,3,3),"unemp"=c(4.0,3.6,1.4,3.7,6.5,5.4),"unemp_lag"=c(NA,4.0,3.6,NA,3.7,6.5))
```

Now, imagine this situation except with thousands of different county-state combinations and over several years. I tried using the lag function, the zoo.lag function, but I couldn't make it take into account the state-county codes.
One possibility is to make a giant for loop, but I think this is too much data (R does not handle for loops well) and I am looking for a cleaner way to do it.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `df$unemp_lag <- lag(df$unemp)` but the sample of your data contains only  county 3 and it is hard imagine grouping by `county`. The previous code should be adde to something like `group_by(county)`

Answer (score 3):

Just an old style base R approach:

```
dsp <- split(df, list(df$state, df$county) )
dsp <- lapply(dsp, function(x) transform(x, unemp_lag =lag(unemp)))
dsp <- unsplit(dsp, list(df$state, df$county))
dsp
yearmonth state county unemp unemp_lag
1   2005-01     1      3   4.0        NA
2   2005-02     1      3   3.6       4.0
3   2005-03     1      3   1.4       3.6
4   2005-01     2      3   3.7        NA
5   2005-02     2      3   6.5       3.7
6   2005-03     2      3   5.4       6.5
```

#### Edit

the `lag` function I used in my solution is the `lag` of `dplyr` (even though I didn't realized it until the BlondedDust comment) and here is a **true** and real pure base R solution (I hope):

```
dsp <- split(df, list(df$state, df$county) )
dsp <- lapply(dsp, function(x) transform(x, unemp_lag = c(NA, unemp[1:length(unemp)-1]) ) )
dsp <- unsplit(dsp, list(df$state, df$county))
dsp
  yearmonth state county unemp unemp_lag
1   2005-01     1      3   4.0        NA
2   2005-02     1      3   3.6       4.0
3   2005-03     1      3   1.4       3.6
4   2005-01     2      3   3.7        NA
5   2005-02     2      3   6.5       3.7
6   2005-03     2      3   5.4       6.5
```

Comment: When I do this with `stats::lag` I get a different result. Are you sure you don't have a different lag function that you are not recognizing? (After loading dplyr I do get that result.) And I have always thought the base `lag` function delivered weird results.

Comment: ohh yes! such a fool I've been, you are right. Am I using `dplyr`'s `lag`? is it possible? `lag(unemp, -2)` is the right code?

Comment: @BondedDust thank you very much. I fixed it with a  **true** base R solution.

Answer (score 3):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,`:=`(unemp_lag1=shift(unemp,n=1L,fill=NA, type="lag")),by=.(state, county)][]

   yearmonth state county unemp unemp_lag1
1:   2005-01     1      3   4.0         NA
2:   2005-02     1      3   3.6        4.0
3:   2005-03     1      3   1.4        3.6
4:   2005-01     2      3   3.7         NA
5:   2005-02     2      3   6.5        3.7
6:   2005-03     2      3   5.4        6.5
```

Answer (score 2):

With [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(state, county) %>% mutate(unemp_lag=lag(unemp))
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: state, county

   yearmonth state county unemp unemp_lag
1   2005-01     1      3   4.0        NA
2   2005-02     1      3   3.6       4.0
3   2005-03     1      3   1.4       3.6
4   2005-01     2      3   3.7        NA
5   2005-02     2      3   6.5       3.7
6   2005-03     2      3   5.4       6.5
```

And with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
> df2 <- as.data.table(df)
> df2[, unemp_lag := c(NA , unemp[-.N]), by=list(state, county)]

   yearmonth state county unemp unemp_lag
1:   2005-01     1      3   4.0        NA
2:   2005-02     1      3   3.6       4.0
3:   2005-03     1      3   1.4       3.6
4:   2005-01     2      3   3.7        NA
5:   2005-02     2      3   6.5       3.7
6:   2005-03     2      3   5.4       6.5
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! One more issue -- I'm trying to make lags from six months prior. I tried adding in the parameter k=-6 or lags=6 but it doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: If data is ordered by month and contains consecutive months: `mutate(unemp_lag=lag(unemp, n=6)) `

Comment: @zero323  `data.table` has `shift` function that does this .See my solution.

Comment: It is correctly ordered, though it doesn't appear to be complete. Is there a way to do this perhaps by making the yearmonth into a Date object?

Comment: The only way I can think of right now is to add missing rows, but is a rather brute force approach. Maybe someone who has more experience with time-series will be able to help you.

Comment: I meant something like this: `tmp <- data.frame(yearmonth=paste0("2015-", stri_pad(1:12, 2, pad="0"))) %>% merge(select(df, state, county));  levels(df$yearmonth) <- levels(foo$tmp); tmp %>% left_join(df)`