# create lag column with starting value 0 and lagging from there

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to calculate a new column in my data where each row uses the lag of the row before it with the first row using a value of 0. I'm trying to do this in `tidyverse` but can't seem to get it sorted it.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample <- 1:10
var <- c(10, 5, 16, 12, 13, 4, 17, 20, 10, 7)
df <- data.frame(sample, var)
```

My new column is called `new_var` and is calculated as `lag(new_var) + sample_i - target - k)`.

I've tried using the the `accumulate()` function but I can't seem to get it right. Here's where I'm at:

```
target <- 11
k <- 2

df %>% 
  mutate(new_var = accumulate(.y = var, 
                              .f = ~.x + .y - target - k,
                              .x = 0))
```

The expected output would be:

```
(-3, 3, 5,-1, 0, -9, 4, 7, -3, 6)
```

I worked it up in excel to show what it would look like:

[image]

To get to that conclusion, the equation in the 'actual new_var' column for sample 1 is as follows (using 0 as the first number in the initial equation):

```
O2 + K7 - $O$3 - $O$4
```

And each subsequent sample lags the 'new_var' column from there (keeping Target and K as constants and using the lag value as the first number in the equation):

```
O3 + K8 - $O$3 - $O$4
```

Comment: It seems like this post might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905001/how-to-create-lag-variables

Comment: Yes, I just edited it to show the expected output of `(-8, -5, -6, -6, -15, -11, -4, -7, -13)`

Comment: @user3585829 Can you explain the calculation of first few values? How do you get `-8, -5, -6` ?

Comment: I made this more explicit in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realize this wasn't explained well on my part. The second value should actually be -11. For value 1, the equation is 0 + 10 - 11 - 2 = -3 and for value 2 then equation would then be -3 + 5 - 11 - 2 = -11. Sorry. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So then all the other calculations would change again? check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you were looking for :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
      mutate(new_var = accumulate(.x = var, 
                                  .f = ~.x + .y - target - k, 
                                  .init = 0)[-1])
#   sample var new_var
#1       1  10      -3
#2       2   5     -11
#3       3  16      -8
#4       4  12      -9
#5       5  13      -9
#6       6   4     -18
#7       7  17     -14
#8       8  20      -7
#9       9  10     -10
#10     10   7     -16
```

which in base R, can be written as :

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x + y - target - k, df$var, accumulate = TRUE, init = 0)[-1]
#[1]  -3 -11  -8  -9  -9 -18 -14  -7 -10 -16
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but perhaps I didn't explain it the correct way. I've edited the question with an example of how it would look in excel so get the results I was expecting. It wasn't that 0 is the first value in the column, it's only that 0 was to be the first value in the equation and then the lag moves from there.

Comment: @user3585829 I have updated the answer, hopefully it gives what you want this time.